# iPod Nano 5th gen Album Artwork

Tags: itunes, ipod, nano, album-art

I am an album artwork fan.  I just got all of these brand new alternate artwork covers for my albums and singles. Eventually, i got bored of them, and i wanted the original ones back.  So i got on iTunes, and changed the original album covers to the primary covers. I synced my ipod, but it still showed the new covers on it, not the originals.  I figured a temporary way to fix it, by deleting the new covers i got, making the originals the default.  There has to be an easier way, though.

p.s. this also works in vice-versa. I will add the new covers, but before i exit, i change the primary cover to the original. When i change it back to the new one, my iPod will still only show the original

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the option in iTunes to sync album artwork and sync the iPod. This will delete all the cover art. Then re-enable the thing and sync it up again, with the covers you want. This may fix all the issues.

If it does not work, try restoring the iPod to the original factory conditions. All your settings and game stats will be gone though, but I do this every time I have a big problem I cannot fix. Just hit the Restore button on the iPod's page in iTunes, and follow the instructions.

Visit my blog http://right-now-in-tech.blogspot.com/ for tech tips and tricks for everyone (and recommend it to others).